# Sql Calculated Group By syntax possibility

Tags: sql, group-by, db2, ibm-midrange

So, I have this shell command that creates a csv from a select, but that's not really important.  The problem I'm having is that one of the fields i'm selecting is an integer field working as a date field yyyymmdd.  So what I want to do is select the field / 100 to get the yyyymm and group by it and the rest of the fields and sum the last one.

```
    SELECT trim(a.F1)||chr(44)||trim(b.F2)||chr(44)||trim(F3)||chr(44)
        ||trim(F4)||chr(44)|||CAST(plandate/100 AS INT)||chr(44)
        ||trim(F5)||chr(44)||trim(F6)||chr(44)||trim(true_dem)
        as "F1, F2, F3, F4, YYYYMM, F5, F6, MONTHLY_DEMAND" 
      from T1 a 
      join T2 b on a.ASDF = b.ASDF 
      WHERE PLANDATE > 20180400
```

So, as you can see right now i'm grabbing all of the dates after a specific date but I don't have the group by logic in, the reason for this is because I can group by all of the "F" fields, but I don't know what to group by for the date filed since it is calculated CAST( plandate/100 AS INT)

I tried doing it like this

```
    SELECT trim(a.f1)||chr(44)||trim(b.f2)||chr(44)||trim(f3)||chr(44)
        ||trim(f4)||chr(44)||CAST( plandate/100 AS INT)||chr(44)
        ||trim(f5)||chr(44)||trim(f6)||chr(44)||sum(true_dem)
        as "f1, f2, f3, f4, YYYYMM, f5, f6, MONTHLY_DEMAND" 
      from t1 a 
      join t2 b on a.f1 = b.f1 
      WHERE PLANDATE > 20180400
      group by a.f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, (CAST( plandate/100 AS INT))
```

but that's obviously not right as i get the [SQL0122] Column PLANDATE or expression in SELECT list not valid. error. pretty much just saying that it's no good.  I'd really like to keep this alias if possible so that i can export it to csv with column headings

ignore the fx and tx stuff I just wanted to chop out any hints to company database stuff.  If it matters I'm running this on I-series DB2 through qsh

Comment: Does the column `plandate`  exist in your table? Can you post the table structure (aka `create table ...` statement)?

Comment: yes it does it's a packed(8, 0) field, I'll try and get you the definition stuff it's kindof a pain doing that without a legit describe command on the ibm

Comment: In Eclipse's "Data Source Explorer" view you can right click on the table and use "Generate DDL", to get the `create table`.

Comment: NAME                COLTYPE  LENGTH     
-----------------   -------- -----------
f1                  CHAR               1
f2                  CHAR               6
f3                  CHAR              10
f4                  CHAR               8
f5                  CHAR               6
PLANDATE            NUMERIC            8
f6                  CHAR              10
f7                  NUMERIC            6
TRUE_DEM            NUMERIC            5
f8                  CHAR              16

Comment: sorry there is no eclipse tied to this mainframe work database i got you a describe table (sort of) there, again I obfiscated a few of the columns other than the PLANDATE which you can see is NUMERIC 8 and TRUE_DEM which you can see as NUMERIC 5  I really don't think it matters though the field is on the table, that's not the issue, the issue is that the I can't group by the field after dividing it by 100, i can group by plandate just fine but i want to group by plandate/100 and thats not possible (with my limited sql ability)

Comment: @IdiotDrake Maybe you could ask a question about how to get that information on IBM i as it really isn't all that hard.

Comment: that way i could ask a question you knew the answer to? sorry it's been asked before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't this also output your column headers as you want them:

```
SELECT   
  a.f1, b.f2, f3, f4, CAST( plandate/100 AS INT) as YYYYMM, 
  f5, f6, sum(true_dem) as MONTHLY_DEMAND
from t1 a join t2 b on a.f1 = b.f1 
WHERE PLANDATE > 20180400
group by a.f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, (CAST( plandate/100 AS INT))
```

If you think you need to do it your way, simply use a subselect to do the aggregation first:

```
SELECT   
    trim(f1)||chr(44)||trim(f2)||chr(44)||trim(f3)||chr(44)||trim(f4)||chr(44)
    ||CAST( plandate/100 AS INT)||chr(44)||trim(f5)||chr(44)||trim(f6)||chr(44)
    ||sum(true_dem) 
    as "f1, f2, f3, f4, YYYYMM, f5, f6, MONTHLY_DEMAND"
FROM (
  SELECT 
    a.f1, b.f2, f3, f4, CAST( plandate/100 AS INT) as YYYYMM, 
    f5, f6, sum(true_dem) as MONTHLY_DEMAND
  from t1 a join t2 b on a.f1 = b.f1 
  WHERE PLANDATE > 20180400
  group by a.f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, (CAST( plandate/100 AS INT))
) t
```

Comment: i obfiscated it but the column headers in the outputed CSV i'm making after running it are different than the ones that it comes in with, the sql statement is wrapped in a shell command to create a csv out of it eg.        qsh cmd('  " ***sqlhere*** "   | sed -n ''/,/p'' | iconv -f 37 -t 367 > output.csv ' )   But i'm testing your second solution now sorry it's weird the csv goes into another input that expects it a certain way

Comment: exelent thanks, the subselect was the way to do it,  syntax is a bit out of order, the group by goes in the outer level and the aliases go on the inner but it got me there thanks alot man the inner select idea never crossed my mind I really appreciate it.